# Rails / Redis / Soulmate - How to limit search results by user role?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

I have set up my app to use Soulmate and soulmate.js for autocomplete. It searches two models - Users and Books. But, I have multiple roles for users - some are authors and some are readers. I only want authors to show up in the results.

Is there a way to limit what is added to Redis as new users sign up, based on their role?

in user.rb (using the "if role = "author") did not work

```
def load_into_soulmate
    loader = Soulmate::Loader.new("authors")
    loader.add("term" => fullname, "id" => self.id, "data" => {
      "link" => Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.user_path(self)
      }) if self.role = "author"
  end

  def remove_from_soulmate
    loader = Soulmate::Loader.new("authors")
      loader.remove("id" => self.id)
  end
```

in pages.js

```
$('#search').soulmate({
    url: '/search/search',
    types: ['books','authors'],
    renderCallback : render,
    selectCallback : select,
    minQueryLength : 2,
    maxResults     : 5
  })
```

Alternatively, could I add the role to what Redis stores and then tell the js to only serve users where role = "author"?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with a conditional in the after_save in user.rb:

```
after_save :load_into_soulmate, :if => :is_author
```

and

```
def is_author
    if self.role == "author"
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end
```

Comment: Just a little suggestion... method name change to `author?` and you merely need one line of code in the method body `role == 'author'` that will return T or F...